# 403 Forbidden Error when trying to display a php website over NGINX Container using Docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have a project I've been working on PHP and decided to learn something useful and new along the way, so I started reading about docker and following a bunch of tutorials in order to install it and create my nginx container.

I've been filling the blanks with numerous guides, official documentation and SO, but I've reached a point where I am not able to find a solution for my issue.

I've been following this guide to try and modify the config files but to no avail: https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-nginx-plus-docker/

I want to note that I've never configured a web server, so I expect some things to be wrong or missing from the files.

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v ~/Desktop/UBERNET:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is my container running the nginx server. With UBERNET/ being the directory where my project lies. (meaning the index.php is located there). This is the resulting docker container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                  NAMES
3edcefa4e06f        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes           0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   web
```

Then as the example shows, I created a Dockerfile and placed it inside the directory `website_content/` as well as adding another folder `conf/`. In the end, I have `website_content/`

`Dockerfile`
`UBERNET/myIndex.php`
`conf/with_two_config_files`

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY UBERNET/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx
COPY conf/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Where I delete both config files and replace them with mine.

Finally, I run this command:

```
sudo docker build ~/Desktop/website_content
```

Which returns:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  549.4kB
Step 1/5 : FROM nginx
 ---> 7e4d58f0e5f3
Step 2/5 : RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b37c4c5d82bb
Step 3/5 : COPY UBERNET/ /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> 328ef2d47407
Step 4/5 : COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx
 ---> 509102fb2af8
Step 5/5 : COPY conf/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
 ---> 7b88205c6dc0
Successfully built 7b88205c6dc0
```

I've tried entering bash mode inside the container and saw that the project directory was successfully copied inside `/usr/share/nginx/html` but it aso copied `conf/` which is not written anywhere on the Dockerfile and instead, they are not being copied in the locations listed on the Dockerfile, so the config files are the original ones. I don't know what could be causing this.

```
root@3edcefa4e06f:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
Dockerfile  UBERNET  conf
```

I've run `Docker logs web` and this is what returns:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2020/10/06 07:22:12 [error] 28#28: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2020:07:22:12 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "-"
2020/10/06 07:22:12 [error] 28#28: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2020:07:22:12 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "-"
2020/10/06 07:22:13 [error] 28#28: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2020:07:22:13 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "-"
2020/10/06 07:22:21 [error] 28#28: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2020:07:22:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "-"
2020/10/06 07:28:53 [error] 28#28: *2 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2020:07:28:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "-"
2020/10/06 07:28:54 [error] 28#28: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
```

Some times it says 404 not found while the last two entries are 403 forbidden, which is what the browser also says.

Finally, these are the default config files:

```
                                             nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

```
                                           default.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

And these are the files I made with the help of a friend, notice how the user changes since I saw the owner of the files of my project was `www-data`

```
                                              nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    
}
```

```
                                        default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/UBERNET;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;


#   location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    }
}
```

I think I've provided everything related to the issue there is, if anything else is needed let me know.

Comment: there are multiple problems here. The issue with the 403 might be related to wrong file permissions in the nginx image since you're adding a volume. Even when you're not mounting the volume, you're copying the UBERNET folder IN html instead of replacing it.

Comment: but these are the small problems. the bigger problems are that the nginx image does not have php. You configured nginx to forward the calls to a 127.0.0.1:9000 which does not exists

Comment: if you want to start working with docker, I'd suggest to first have the php application running on apache (using the php:apache-buster image)

Comment: once that stuff is working, I'd check how to port your setup on `docker-compose` and start adding an nginx and add a reverse proxy for the other php image.

Comment: from there you'll be able to replace the php:apache-buster with something like php:fpm-alpine.

Comment: Than you @Stefano, you have provided a lot of insight. It's a bummer to not be able to pull this off, but I will let the container as it is and try using the apache+php image you mentioned. If I may ask, does it follow a similar procedure as nginx or creating an apache image has nothing to do with how I created the nginx one?

Comment: the process is similar but the setup is different. I'd suggest to read the `php:<version>-apache` chapter under `Image Variants` in https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: I think it's going to be easier than the current setup. less stuff to worry about.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll read and start with the documentation you have provided!